# flutter REST API reading with nested JSON link

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I'm integrating an API I found on [Github](https://github.com/fawazahmed0/quran-api) and In the JSON data there is a link object which leads to another JSON file. this particular REST API structure is as follows.

```
    {
"aar_sheikhmahmoudab": {
        "name": "aar-sheikhmahmoudab",
        "author": "Sheikh Mahmoud Abdel Qader Hamz And Group Of Scholars",
        "language": "Afar",
        "direction": "ltr",
        "source": "https://qurancomplex.gov.sa/",
        "comments": "This translation was OCRed, in case you find any mistakes,
        "link": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fawazahmed0/quran-api@1/editions/aar-sheikhmahmoudab.json",
        "linkmin": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fawazahmed0/quran-api@1/editions/aar-sheikhmahmoudab.min.json"
    },
    "ace_tgkhmahjiddinju": {
        "name": "ace-tgkhmahjiddinju",
        "author": "Tgk. H. Mahjiddin Jusuf",
        "language": "Achinese",
        "direction": "ltr",
        "source": "https://www.islamic-invitation.com/",
        "comments": "This translation was OCRed, in case you find any mistakes,
        "link": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fawazahmed0/quran-api@1/editions/ace-tgkhmahjiddinju.json",
        "linkmin": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fawazahmed0/quran-api@1/editions/ace-tgkhmahjiddinju.min.json"
    },
}
```

and the `link` object leads to another JSON data

```
{
 "quran": [
        {
            "chapter": 1,
            "verse": 1,
            "text": "«بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم»"
        },
        {
            "chapter": 1,
            "verse": 2,
            "text": "«الحمد لله» جملة خبرية قصد بها الثناء على الله بمضمونها من أنه تعالى: مالك لجميع الحمد من الخلق أو مستحق لأن يحمدوه، والله علم على المعبود بحق «ربِّ العالمين» أي مالك جميع الخلق من الإنس والجن والملائكة والدواب وغيرهم، وكل منها يُطلق عليه عالم، يقال عالم الإنس وعالم الجن إلى غير ذلك، وغلب في جمعه بالياء والنون أولي العلم على غيرهم، وهو من العلامة لأنه علامة على موجده"
        },
]
}
```

so my question is that how can I integrate a JSON inside another JSON in my app. any tutorial on this can help me a lot?

Comment: you want to fetch data from first json then call the link at the same time to get another json?

Comment: so do i need to create models for every link?

Comment: I would prefer to create models to avoid bugs

Comment: Thanks very much